# in chrome browser trying to refresh one frame from other frame in the same window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using this method to fresh other frame in the same window using java script

```
function updateTree(val) { 

  if (val == 1) {
   parent.frames['left'].location.reload();
  } else if(val == 2) {
   parent.frames['bottom'].location.reload();
  } 

}
```

its working in both IE and Mozilla but is not working in  Chrome Browser(3.0.195.38).
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try this and tell me what gets alerted in Chrome: `alert(parent.frames.length);`

Comment: does .reload() work at all in chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something along these lines:

```
parent.left.location = parent.left.location.href
```

or

```
parent.frames['left'].location = parent.frames['left'].location.href
```

There may be a mechanism ignoring 'refreshing' to the same url. in that case, you can order a temporary move to "about:blank" and follow it by a move to the original href.

Y.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving reply,
for me 
parent.frames[0].location = parent.frames[0].location.href this is working fine
thank u somuch

Comment: Happy to help! If you would be so kind as to accept the answer (green check-mark), it will be much appreciated.